# How to fix this linker error in Developer Command Prompt for VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

How are you doing?
The error message:
nativehost.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__get_hostfxr_path@12 referenced in function "bool __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::load_hostfxr(void)" (?load_hostfxr@?A0x85d553db@@YA_NXZ) [C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\Blazor\samples\core\hosting\HostWithHostFxr\src\NativeHost\NativeHost.csproj]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64\3.1.6\runtimes\win-x64\native\nethost.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86

I have installed DotNetCore SDK(3.1.6) and it is the latest version in my environment,
and get_hostfxr_path is a function from nethost.h
I think I need to link the nethost.lib, but I don't how to link the file in Developer Command Prompt for VS2019

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the x64 native Developer Prompt or the 32-bit one?

Comment: I tried both Developer Command Prompt and x86 Native Tools Command Prompt. No luck.

Comment: Thank you. Ran in Native x64 Tools Command Prompt worked

Answer (score 0):

The Developer Command Prompt for VS is x86 (32-bit) tools. If you want x64 native tools, you should use the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt". The "x86_x64 Tools Command Prompt" would also work to target x64 native.